# Python/django environment error in ubuntu

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, ubuntu

**Environment:**

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'myapp',
'south']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')
```

**Traceback:**

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  215.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  197.                 return self.login(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in login
  330.         return login(request, **defaults)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  75.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py" in login
  49.     current_site = get_current_site(request)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py" in get_current_site
  103.         current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/sites/models.py" in get_current
  43.             raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the Django \"sites framework\" without having set the SITE_ID setting. Create a site in your database and set the SITE_ID setting to fix this error.")

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/
Exception Value: You're using the Django "sites framework" without having set the SITE_ID setting. Create a site in your database and set the SITE_ID setting to fix this error.
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Django, but have you tried creating a site in your database and setting the SITE_ID setting to fix this error?

Comment: posting a traceback is not a question - and anyway, the exception message contains all the informations you need to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Set the site_id in the settings.py as 1 or comment out this statement from Installed Applications:
'django.contrib.sites',